# Regexp and pspell_check with UTF-8 (Umlaute)

Tags: php, regex, aspell

I'm having trouble with this piece of code. What it should do is take a string, split it by word, then check it against a dictionary. However when the string contains an "Umlaut" ÄäÖöÜü it splits it there.

I'm pretty sure the problem is `[A-ZäöüÄÖÜ\']`  it seems i'm including the special charackters wrong, but how?

```
$string = "Rechtschreibprüfung";      
preg_match_all("/[A-ZäöüÄÖÜ\']{1,16}/i", $string, $words);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($words[0]); ++$i) {
    if (!pspell_check($pspell_link, $words[0][$i])) {
        $array[] = $words[0][$i];            
    }
}
```

result:

```
$array[0] = Rechtschreibprü"
$array[1] = "fung"
```

Comment: You just need `'/\p{L}+/u'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks seems to work, care to post as an answer? Since i'm never grasping these things any good reading recomendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match a chunk of Unicode letters, you can use

```
'/\p{L}+/u'
```

The `\p{L}` matches any Unicode letter, `+` matches one or more occurrenes of the preceding subpattern and the `/u` modifier treats the pattern and string as Unicode strings.

To only match whole words, use word boundaries:

```
'/\b\p{L}+\b/u'
```

If you have diacritics, also add `\p{M}`:

```
'/\b[\p{M}\p{L}]+\b/u'
```